# Why does Scipy dendrogram distance axis scale changes with the number of variables?

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a distributional analysis algorithm for words. It generates observational vectors for each target word and from this table, I use stats.spearmanr() to calculate the distances (rescaled from [-1,1] to [0,1]), generating a distance matrix (Y). Then I use hierarchy.average() to obtain the clustering (Z). Finally, a dendrogram is generated and plotted.

The problem I have is this: the dendrogram scale varies with the number of target words. I was assuming that its distance axis varied along the [0,1] range (as obtained (and rescaled) with spearmanr()), as presented above. But it is [0, 0.5] for, say, 50 words, but [0, 1] for 150, and [0, 2] for 1000.

Why is that so (that the distance scale have values bigger than the ones in Y)?

I'd appreciate any ideas on this issue, because I can't seem to find any hint in the documentation and over the web (which makes me worried about making the wrong questions...). And I'd need a fixed scale or at least a way to know which one the dendrogram is using, for cut level specification purposes. Thanks in advance for any help.

The simplified code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# Estatísticas e visualização
import numpy as np
import scipy, random
import scipy.stats

# Clusterização e visualização do dendrograma
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def remap(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min

random.seed('7622')

sizes = [50, 250, 500, 1000, 2000]

for n in sizes:
  # Generate observation matrix
  X = []
  for i in range(n):
    vet = []
    for j in range(300):
      # Generate random observations
      vet.append(random.randint(0, 50))

    X.append(vet)

  # X is a matrix where lines are variables (target words) and columns are observations (contexts of occurrence)
  Y = scipy.stats.spearmanr(X, axis=1)

  # Y rescaling
  for i in range(len(Y[0])):
    Y[0][i] = [ remap(v, -1, 1, 0, 1) for v in Y[0][i] ]

  print 'Y [', np.matrix(Y[0]).min(), ',', np.matrix(Y[0]).max(), ']'

  # Clustering
  Z = hac.average(Y[0])

  print 'n=', n, \
        'Z [', min([ el[2] for el in Z ]), ',', max([ el[2] for el in Z ]), ']'
```

[UPDATE] Results of the above code:

```
Y [ 0.401120498124 , 1.0 ]
n= 50 Z [ 0.634408300876 , 0.77633631869 ]
Y [ 0.379375733574 , 1.0 ]
n= 250 Z [ 0.775241869849 , 0.969704246048 ]
Y [ 0.37559031365 , 1.0 ]
n= 500 Z [ 0.935671154717 , 1.16505319575 ]
Y [ 0.370600337649 , 1.0 ]
n= 1000 Z [ 1.19646327361 , 1.47897594053 ]
Y [ 0.359010408057 , 1.0 ]
n= 2000 Z [ 1.56890165007 , 1.96898566034 ]
```

Comment: I found out (something probably obvious) that the values for the distance axis of the dendrogram come from the third column of Z. Checking the range of this column, I see that they grow as the number of words (and maybe clusters) grow too. What I don't understand yet: how this numbers are obtained (with the 'average' method) and why do they eventually fall out of the range [0,1] of the correlations between words in Y...

Comment: I tried this with simulated data: `n = 1000; dist = np.random.uniform(0.5, 0.9, size=(n*(n+1)//2,)); Z = hierarchy.average(dist);` - no such issue observed, the cluster distances are all within the range of original distances. Try to create and post a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated the example code with a fully running one. You'll be able to see the scale variation as 'n' increases (say, 50, 250, 500, 1000, 2000).